# How to intercept bot messages in SDK4

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have an SDK 4 bot, logging user interactions to Blob storage. I would also like to log bot responses also. In SDK 3 I did this with something like ...

```
bot.use({
    // Code for handling message receives
    receive: function (session, event, next) {
        var userId = session.address.user.id;
        logger.logUserConversation(session.text, userId, session.address.conversation.id, userId);
        next();
    },
    // Code for handling message sends
    send: function (event, next) {
        var text = event.text;    
        if(!event.text) {
            text = "Attachments sent";
        }
        logger.logUserConversation(text, 'bot', event.address.conversation.id, event.address.user.id);
        next();
    }
});
```

In SDK 4, I am able to configure [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-create-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=jsaddmiddleware%2Cjsimplementmiddleware%2Cjsmiddlewareshortcircuit%2Cjsfallback) which intercepts user activity, but I cannot seem to intercept bot activity. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation, but I am new to SDK 4 and might be missing something.

Anybody know how I can intercept both user and bot events, so that I can log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already 2 samples in Node.js in the official samples repository:

- 1 called "Logger": https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.logger
- 1 called "transcript Logger": https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/26.transcript-logger

I gave a try to the 1st one and can confirm that it logs both user input and bot replies. It is logging every activity, even `ConversationUpdate`.

See example of transcript generated below:

```
 Activity Received: { type: 'conversationUpdate',
  membersAdded: [ { id: '1', name: 'Bot' } ],
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: '36e25420-ec19-11e8-8040-2ba105e71021|livechat' },
  id: '370f7ea0-ec19-11e8-9ee4-fb60855d29c5',
  localTimestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:07.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  timestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:07.689Z,
  from:
   { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6',
     name: 'User',
     role: 'user' },
  locale: '',
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58083' } 

 Activity Received: { type: 'conversationUpdate',
  membersAdded:
   [ { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6', name: 'User' } ],
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: '36e25420-ec19-11e8-8040-2ba105e71021|livechat' },
  id: '3711c890-ec19-11e8-9ee4-fb60855d29c5',
  localTimestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:07.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  timestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:07.705Z,
  from:
   { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6',
     name: 'User',
     role: 'user' },
  locale: '',
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58083' } 

 Activity Received: { text:
   'I am a bot that demonstrates custom logging. We will have a short conversation where I ask a few questions  to collect your name and age, then store those values in UserState for later use. after this you will be able to find a log of the conversation in the folder set by the transcriptsPath environment variable Say anything to continue.',
  inputHint: 'acceptingInput',
  channelId: 'emulator',
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58083',
  conversation: { id: '36e25420-ec19-11e8-8040-2ba105e71021|livechat' },
  from: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  recipient:
   { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6',
     name: 'User',
     role: 'user' },
  replyToId: '3711c890-ec19-11e8-9ee4-fb60855d29c5',
  type: 'message',
  timestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:08.408Z } 

 Activity Received: { type: 'message',
  text: 'test',
  from:
   { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6',
     name: 'User',
     role: 'user' },
  locale: '',
  textFormat: 'plain',
  timestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:23.421Z,
  channelData: { clientActivityId: '1542645367574.7109285295569892.0' },
  entities:
   [ { type: 'ClientCapabilities',
       requiresBotState: true,
       supportsTts: true,
       supportsListening: true } ],
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: '36e25420-ec19-11e8-8040-2ba105e71021|livechat' },
  id: '406fdad0-ec19-11e8-9ee4-fb60855d29c5',
  localTimestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:23.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58083' } 

 Activity Received: { text: 'What is your name, human?',
  inputHint: 'expectingInput',
  channelId: 'emulator',
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58083',
  conversation: { id: '36e25420-ec19-11e8-8040-2ba105e71021|livechat' },
  from: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  recipient:
   { id: 'fd3fd64d-6297-4e36-98c5-ee398857f2b6',
     name: 'User',
     role: 'user' },
  replyToId: '406fdad0-ec19-11e8-9ee4-fb60855d29c5',
  type: 'message',
  timestamp: 2018-11-19T16:36:23.443Z }
```

More details about the code that generated that is available on the project, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/26.transcript-logger/customLogger.js). If you look at it, the main point is:

```
if (activity.value === 'endOfInput') {
    console.log(this.conversations[id]);
    var transcriptfileName = util.format('%s/log_%s.transcript', process.env.transcriptsPath, id);
    fs.writeFile(transcriptfileName, JSON.stringify(this.conversations[id], null, 3), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    delete this.conversations[id];
}
```

Comment: Doh! Should have spotted those. Thanks a lot.

Comment: unfortunately above links are not available now.